# How can I change react-native-swiper-flatlist style of pagination dots?

Tags: javascript, react-native

How can I change `react-native-swiper-flatlist` style of pagination dots? Is this possible?

```
 <View style={styles.container}>
    <SwiperFlatList
      autoplay={false}
      autoplayLoop={false}
      index={0}
      showPagination
    >
      <View style={styles.child}>
        <Image style={styles.img} source={pic} />
        <Text style={styles.text}>Biz sizə nə vəd edirik ?</Text>
        <Text style={styles.smallText}>Dizaynın qiymətləndirilməsində, oxunan mətnin oxucunun diqqətini yayındırması bir həqiqətdir. Lorem Ipsum istifadə etmənin əsas məqsədi odur.</Text>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.child}>
        <Image style={styles.img} source={pic} />
        <Text style={styles.text}>Sizin rahatlığınız üçün çalışırıq</Text>
        <Text style={styles.smallText}>Dizaynın qiymətləndirilməsində, oxunan mətnin oxucunun diqqətini yayındırması bir həqiqətdir. Lorem Ipsum istifadə etmənin əsas məqsədi odur.</Text>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.child}>
        <Image style={styles.img} source={pic} />
        <Text style={styles.text}>Daima yanınızdayıq!</Text>
        <Text style={styles.smallText}>Dizaynın qiymətləndirilməsində, oxunan mətnin oxucunun diqqətini yayındırması bir həqiqətdir. Lorem Ipsum istifadə etmənin əsas məqsədi odur.</Text>
      </View>
    </SwiperFlatList>
  </View>
```

Comment: Improved grammar and formatting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `paginationStyleItem` prop for styling dots.

for more info [see this npm information](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-swiper-flatlist#props)

Comment: it is for the container of that dots.

Comment: i want to change dots width